# Parse url encoded body with Restify

Tags: node.js, httprequest, restify

I'm not able to do url encoded posts to my node.js API using restify. I have the following setup of my restify app:

```
app.use(restify.acceptParser(app.acceptable));                                  
app.use(restify.queryParser());                                                 
app.use(restify.urlEncodedBodyParser());
```

But when I'm requesting my app using curl with the following request:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d quantity=50 http://app:5000/feeds
```

I get the following input body in my view:

```
console.log(req.body)  // "quantity=50"
```

Thanks in advance,

Mattias

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The default setup for Restify places parsed parameters in `req.params`. This is done by both the `queryParser` and the different `bodyParser` middlewares.

So to access the `quantity` parameter, use `req.params.quantity`.

If you really want to use `req.body` instead, you need to pass `mapParams : false` to the `bodyParser` constructor:

```
app.use(restify.plugins.urlEncodedBodyParser({ mapParams : false }));
```

Now `req.body` will contain the parsed parameters.

Comment: The moment I use the parser my entire service becomes unresponsive on any URL. It simply never returns and no breakpoints are hit

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno that's usually a sign that the middleware isn't passing the requests along the middleware chain. This answer is pretty old, perhaps something changed since then that may cause the behaviour you're witnessing.

Comment: I discovered that independently but you are/were correct. The CORS module was stopping the whole thing. Honestly, restify is not really impressing me.